# USB Stick Becoming Write Protected

Tags: usb-flash-drive, perl, write-protect

I am running windows 7. I have a 2GB flash-drive running a strawberry Perl portable edition. I was spending time installing CPAN modules this morning when suddenly my disk became write protected. Unfortunately, I cant do anything to diagnose because it is write only. I cant even reformat. The drive was washed accidentally, but that was months ago. Did perl do this to me, or is it just my flashdrive?

note: I do NOT have a write protection switch.

Comment: Do you have the option to test on another PC? Sometimes USB Sticks stop working on one PC/OS but keep working on others. It would at least allow you to access the data.

Comment: Yes, I have tried on multiple computers.